# QThread Cannot Connect signal and slot

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a web server that I know works when run on its own, that I need to start with the application. I need to start it in a separate thread because the server runs an infinite event loop. For some reason it's not connecting though.

The `WebServer::start` method holds the infinite loop. The signal is emitting but the `start` method isn't firing. This is as minimal example I can show because it's based on the `QThread` example from the documentation that does work.

```cpp
class WebServerController : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

   private:
    QThread serverThread;
    WebServer* server;

   public:
    explicit WebServerController();
    void startServer();
    ~WebServerController();
   public slots:
    void handleExit();
   signals:
    void initServer();
};


WebServerController::WebServerController() {
    server = new WebServer();
    server->moveToThread(&serverThread);
    connect(&serverThread, &QThread::finished, server, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &WebServerController::initServer, server, &WebServer::start);
    connect(server, &WebServer::onExit, this, &WebServerController::handleExit);
}

void WebServerController::startServer() {
    qDebug() << "debugging";
    emit initServer();
}

// handle the exit
WebServerController::~WebServerController() {
    serverThread.quit();
    serverThread.wait();
}

void WebServerController::handleExit() { qDebug() << "Exiting"; }
```

```cpp
class WebServer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
   public:
    explicit WebServer(QString root = HTTP_PATH, unsigned int port = 8080);
    unsigned int port();  // return the port number

   public slots:
    void start();

   private:
    unsigned int _port;
    QString _root;
    struct mg_mgr eventManager;
    struct mg_connection *connection;
    int connectServer(unsigned int port);
    static void serve(struct mg_connection *, int ev, void *ev_data,
                      void *fn_data);
    static const unsigned int ports[13];
    // static because we want all connections to catch the same interupt
    static int s_signo;
    static void signal_handler(int signo);

   signals:
    void onExit(int exitStatus);
};
```

Comment: Where do you start the thread? Please provide a minimal, compilable example.

Comment: Definitely need to see the contents of the WebServer::start() if you're saying there's an infinite loop there. As a general comment, I'd move the `server->moveToThread(&serverThread);` line after your connections (you may be starting things running before you get a chance to make the connect calls).

Comment: @chehrlic You're comment solved the problem for me. I wasn't starting the thread. Once I added a call to `serverThread.start` it worked